# Save empty NSArray to disk

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

I have a NSMutableArray. It can be empty or have a number of propertyList objects (In my case just NSNumber objects).
I want to save it to disk in xml format, so I'm using.

```
// In the interface    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;

// In the implementation
if ([self.myArray writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES])
{
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

If the array is empty ( an empty initialized NSMutableArray) in the moment the method is called the method returns NO and the operation is not done, so the old data is not overwritten.

How can I write an empty array to disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure `self.myArray` is in fact an “empty *initialized* NSMutableArray”? For me, telling an empty array to write itself to a file works fine.

The behavior you're observing, that the message returns `NO`, is consistent with `self.myArray` returning `nil`, which means it is neither empty nor non-empty, because you don't have an array at all. With no array, there is nothing to send a message to, so the message returns (in this case) `NO`.

Make absolutely sure that `self.myArray` is in fact returning an array, empty or otherwise, at the point where you're trying to send it a message. The logging code and output you used to verify that would be a great thing for you to add to your question.

Comment: You were right, I messed the code reimplementing and didn't initialize the property, but since I have never save an array to disk before I just thought I did something wrong with that.